# clang pass variables by reference

Tags: gcc, clang

I am compiling the following code using clang 3.4.2 ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
void haa(int& j){
    j=1;
}
int main(){
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
hello.c:3:13: error: expected ')'
void haa(int& j){
        ^
hello.c:3:9: note: to match this '('
void haa(int& j){
    ^
hello.c:3:13: error: parameter name omitted
void haa(int& j){
        ^
hello.c:4:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'j'
        j=1;
    ^
3 errors generated.
```

Compiling the same with gcc gives no errors or warnings...
Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: I can compile it with clang version  3.4-1ubuntu3 using `clang -o test.out test.c`. Your clang installation may be faulty, you might want to check the stdio.h file used by clang.

Comment: I guess its not a problem with the stdio file .. as i can remove the printf and the #include lines and still get the same error ..

Comment: Does renaming `haa` to `hab`  make a difference? What about adding new lines before `haa`?

Comment: No it did not make any difference .. i get the same error message .. and as you can see in the error message , clang is complaining about the ampersand sign ,i.e. passing a variable by reference ..

Comment: Ahm, yes, that is not valid C, right? If you compile it with clang++, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that pass by reference (with references and not pointers) is not a c but a c++ feature.

You need to compile the code with a c++ compiler such as `g++` or `clang++`. Changing the file extension to `.cpp` also works, as this tells the compiler to treat it as a c++.

Comment: Thanks ! I forgot that!